# Is it possible to make Chrome keep the sound while casting tab (not screen)?

Tags: google-chrome, audio-streaming, chromecast, mute

Google Chrome has two `Cast` options: `Cast tab` and `Cast screen`.

`Cast screen` automatically mutes the operating system's sound, but it can be normally unmuted and thus both the presenter and the viewers can hear sounds.

`Cast tab` however does not mute the sound visually (in the volume mixer), but it does silence it nonetheless. Since one can't merely unmute (since officially it's not muted), is there any way to stop this "unofficial" mute?

That is, to use **`Cast tab`** (**not** `Cast screen`) while letting both the presenter and the viewers hear sounds.

[image: Browser Cast option]

[image: Cast tab or screen]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to make Chrome not automatically unmute while casting the screen?](https://superuser.com/questions/1729022/is-it-possible-to-make-chrome-not-automatically-unmute-while-casting-the-screen)

Comment: Thanks, but it does not, it's the opposite question by myself. Cast tab and Cast screen are 2 different settings. Each question is about only one of them.